# How to set Android version in Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse, version

I've written a first app for Android with Eclipse. I've published it but I'm noticing that on the app page it doesn't show the Android minimum version supported, you can see it here:

https://market.android.com/details?id=com.yellowhouse.everydayquotes

I've searched in the project files and I've found that in project.properties there is the following line:

target=android-15

is that the correct place to set the Android version? Am I missing something? Why does it not appear on the page? Thanks.

Comment: You have to add an attribute [minSdkVersion](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html) in the manifest.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the "target=android-15" that you have is for your emulator or your test device which you want to launch your app with

To answer to your question, you need to set the minSDK version in your android manifest file
like that

```
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
      package="tfe.rma.ciss.be"
      android:versionCode="1"
      android:versionName="1.0">
     <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="8" />

</manifest>
```

Answer (score 1):

To set the minimum required android version for your app, you need to use `uses-sdk` element inside your AndroidManifest.xml file:

```
<manifest ...>
    <uses-sdk android:minSdkVersion="4" android:targetSdkVersion="7"/>
    ...
</manifest>
```

Version 4 means Android 1.6.  Read up information on android manifest to see the correct sdk version numbers: http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/uses-sdk-element.html